# IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3 no reconoce el Framework de PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3 al momento de ejecutar una Java Enterprise-> Web project application-> JSF-> PrimeFaces. 
No me reconoce las librerías de este ultimo teniendo en cuenta que ya agregue  a la biblioteca PrimeFaces.Jar la versión 5.2
El servidor que estoy utilizando es Weblogic 12.0.
Podrían indicarme con un ejemplo básico los pasos que debo seguir para que se ejecute sin problemas PrimeFaces en IntelliJ IDEA.

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
            <title>PrimeFaces</title>
        </f:facet>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>

        <p:layout fullPage="true">

            <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Header
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                Footer
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                <p:menu>
                    <p:submenu label="Resources">
                        <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />

                    </p:submenu>

                </p:menu>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                Welcome to PrimeFaces
            </p:layoutUnit>

        </p:layout>

    </h:body>

</f:view>
```

What it shows IntelliJ IDEA
[image: What it shows IntelliJ IDEA]

What should show Compiled in Netbeans 8
[image: What should show Compiled in Netbeans 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisa el web.xml de tu aplicación, concretamente el valor de welcome-file-list.
Si existe modifícalo de forma que quede así:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/welcomePrimefaces.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

(Y si no existe, añádelo)

Comment: Ok era lo que faltaba para reconocer el framework gracias.